# Android ContentResolver with data on a USB stick

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-contentresolver, usb-flash-drive

I am writing an application for an Andriod tablet (3.2) that plays media that in my case is stored on a USB stick.  However, I noticed that when the USB stick is NOT plugged in, the ContentResolver returns songs that are stored on the USB stick.  Is there a way to make sure my content resolver only returns media that can actually be found in the filesystem?  I.E. stop showing me songs on a USB stick that isn't plugged in right now?

Comment: Android has no support for "a USB stick".

Comment: My Acer A500 has a full sized USB port.  It works just fine

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: the Android *SDK* has no support for "a USB stick".

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.  I don't think the actual physical media is all that important.  The important thing is that my ContentResolver is returning media that does not exist.  Is there a way to refresh the media database?

Comment: Are other applications (e.g., Gallery) seeing the files after you remove the USB stick? If so, probably you are experiencing some bug in Acer's USB stick/`MediaStore` logic, and you'd need to talk to them more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a way to force a refresh, but it looks like Android does refresh its database periodically on its own.  Not sure how 4+ handles it